# VideoJS Skin not showing on FF or Chorme

Tags: html, video, video.js

Im driving myself a little bit crazy trying to realize why the videojs skin is not being showed.
I apply a class and use the default skin css values in the documentatation, but in firefox o chrome i just cant see it
any idea?
i have a sample page here: [sample](http://pabloscillia.com.ar/clientes/n/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You need to do one of two things to initialise the player. Without that you have a plain video element, not an unskinned video.js.

1. Include a `data-setup='{}'` attribute on the `video` element.
2. Call `videojs('id_of_video')`

Comment: ufffffffffffffffffff, that was easy and stupid, thanks a lot for the answer